# Stop Apple clang from adding Xcode paths to standard include paths

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang

Apple's clang appears to magically include Xcode header files which conflict with my code.  For example, they define `stoi()` while standard C++ headers do not.  Clang does not do this on other platforms, e.g. FreeBSD.

Example of error on Mac OS:

```
$ clang -I. -I../../../include -c compile.cpp
compile.cpp:949:18: error: call to 'stoi' is ambiguous
                            arg.iValue = stoi(current.token);
                                         ^~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/string:4019:37: note:
      candidate function
_LIBCPP_FUNC_VIS int                stoi  (const string& __str, size_t* ...
                                    ^
```

This compile works fine on FreeBSD.

The problem is because in addition to the standard C++ headers in /usr/include/c++, Apple clang is including the headers in the Xcode application tool chain.  Is there some way to turn that off without using the `-nobuiltininc` flag?

Comment: Compile using `--stdlib=libstdc++` instead of `--stdlib=libc++`. The libc++ implementation is c++11, which means that this routine will be present. This is an actual issue you're probably going to have to address as a newer version of gcc will also define the routine if you compile with `--std=c++11`

Comment: @Petesh -- that's exactly the solution I needed.  You should post your comment as an answer.  I will mark it accepted.  Thanks much!

Comment: show the full error. You probably have a conflicting `stoi` you'd want to get rid of.

Comment: I do have have conflicting `stoi` but I don't want to get rid of it.  We are not building against C++11 on FreeBSD -- yet.  When we do, then yes.  I'm just trying to make my dev environment on my Mac work enough to allow me to development locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default C++ library for newer versions of clang on OSX is `libc++`, which is a pretty full implementation of the C++11 standard. The headers are all C++11, and there are no conditional sections to remove methods that should only be available in that standard (e.g. attempting to compile using `--std=c++03` doesn't have the desired effect.

The version of `stdlib++` that's present in the apple environment doesn't have this issue as (1) it's not a complete implementation of the C++11 standard, and (2) you can actually compile for older c++ standards.

As a result, if you compile using `--stdlib=libstdc++`, you are compiling against the GNU standard library headers and library which don't have the issue with the definition of `std::stoi` (and others routines if I'm interpreting the question correctly).

Bear in mind, though, that you have to compile **every** c++ element of your project with this flag, as otherwise you end up with code that has been compiled with different standard libraries and they will not link together.

The real problem, though, is that if you start using C++11 features and start compiling explicitly with `--std=c++11`, then you're probably going to encounter this problem at some point in the future with gcc as well. Newer versions of the compiler support more of the C++11 standard, and so would define this routine in the headers and you're back to square one.